# ”变成“ vs “变成为” 有什么不同？

Tags: grammar, verbs

我不清楚 ”为“ 对 像 ”变成“ ”改造“ 这样的词的影响是什么。比方说，“变成为”，“改造为” 跟 “变成” “改造“ 有什么不同的地方。如果一个词是改变的意思，总是可以加 “为” 吗？

I am not sure what the impact of "为" is on verbs that indicate change. For instance, "变成“ vs "变成为“ or "改造" vs. "改造为". In addition, I am not sure whether "为" can be added to all verbs that indicate change or just a few specific ones.

Answer (score 1):

"变成为" is kind of redundant. It is the same as "变成".

Here the "stem" of verb is "变", while "成" and "为" are two "suffixes" that have similar meaning.

"改造" and "改造为" are totally different. "改造" means to change something. "改造为" means to change **into** (become) something.

Comment: Are there any words for changing into something that you can't add "为“ to?

Answer (score 1):

為 sometimes have the same meanings of 是. And 是 showed that somethings after 是 is used to describe somethings before 是. for example: 石頭變成為一顆漂亮的寶石 showed that somethings after 為(一顆漂亮的寶石) is used to describe somethings before 為(石頭變成). So in this example, you can know that somethings **changed from stone**(the meaning of 石頭變成) is **a beautiful gem**(the meaning of 一顆漂亮的寶石).

While sometimes you don't need to use 為. That's say 石頭變成一顆漂亮的寶石 is complete for people to understand.

I think that sometimes people tend to use 為 or 成 when there is too less word. 成 have the meaning of become somethings. For example, if there is only 變 in 石頭變一顆漂亮的寶石 people tend to add 為 or 成 after 變 to form 石頭變為一顆漂亮的寶石 or 石頭變成一顆漂亮的寶石.

Comment: I think you mean "gem" instead of "germ".

Comment: @Agrit Sorry, error fixed.